# Leaflet search GeoServer layer

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, web-mapping

I'm  new to web mapping, but I've managed to put together a fairly simple web map using Leaflet:
http://www.hcswgis.com/globalmapper/

It has most of the functionality that I want using the available plugins; One feature that it's lacking is a way to search by a parcel ID, which in turn puts a marker where that parcel is, and zooms into it.

In my web map there is a parcel Mapbox layer, but I don't believe there is a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish with that layer because it's tiles and a UTFGrid.

I thought about adding the parcel layer onto my GeoServer. From that I thought I could potentially use the plugin https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search to query the GeoServer parcel layer to find whatever parcel ID is being searched and zoom into it.

Is that possible?

I'm open to any alternative solutions that accomplishes the goal. Keep in mind we're talking about around 80,000 features to search.

Answer (score 3):

Although I've not looked at any leaflet plugins the that might make your life easier, you could typically carry out a WFS request to query the data and filter by an attribute which is what you're doing here.

I'd look into [GetFeature](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#getfeature) requests

Comment: The plugin you suggested will be doing this behind the scenes, if you want to do it without any plugins I would consider [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187937/loading-geojson-layers-from-geoserver-to-leaflet-map-based-on-the-current-boundi)